# what should I do to use boost library for my c++ project in VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

Hi everyone this is my first time for using boost library in c++ project so I actually  dont know what should I do for it.

Here is part of my code that is related with boost :

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct op_or  {};
struct op_and {};
struct op_not {};

typedef std::string var;
template <typename tag> struct binop;
template <typename tag> struct unop;
```

I've downloaded boost_1_55 and extract `boost/spirit` ,`boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp` and `boost/lexical_cast.hpp`
 into C:// .After that I've added them into my project by right clicking project and choosing add existing item . 
Now, If I replace my headers with below

```
#include "qi.hpp"
#include "phoenix.hpp"
#include "phoenix_operator.hpp"
#include "recursive_wrapper.hpp"
#include "lexical_cast.hpp"
```

errors on header files are gone but compiler still gives error at :

```
 #include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
 #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

lines. It says that "*error name followed by :: must be a class or namespace*". So is there anyone to know what should I do ?

Comment: There's very little chance you'll be able to extract a few subfolders from boost and make it work (and why you'd dump them into *C:* is beyond me, but whatever). Unless you have some severe space restrictions, my advice is to extract all of boost, and add the root folder to your include path. If really want to extract just a few libraries, then google *boost bcp* for information on how to do that.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for reply, how could I include root folder include path ?

Comment: @eday _'how could I include root folder include path'_ Use the `-I<path-to-boost>` option to add additional include folders to be searched. And to prevent the next question: Also make sure to add the appropriate libraries to be linked (`-l<libname>`) and library search paths' (`-L<lib-folder>`) to your project.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to install the latest version of [NuGet](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca).
Then use the Extension Gallery to search/find/install the boost [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost/).

The added boost.targets will add the automatically add the paths to resolve the libs and headers for you.